# Difference between HABTM relationship and 2 $belongsTo relationship with a third model

Tags: php, cakephp, activerecord, cakephp-model

I'm creating a project management system which projects are assigned to users

What's the difference between creating a Model `ProjectsUser` and defining 2 `$belongsTo` relationship and defining `HABTM` relationships in both `Project` and `User` models? What would be the most correct way, though? And how do I save the data in the `projects_users` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, if you want to be able to save or delete rows only from the join table (the one with 2 IDs), then it is much more simple using three models associated through both a hasMany and a belongsTo association.

You can also retrieve data from the join table directly and do the queries you want much more easily

This is what CakePHP documentation says refering to HABTM and saving data:

> However, in most cases it’s easier to make a model for the join table and setup hasMany, belongsTo associations as shown in example above instead of using HABTM association.

Here you can find more the full text:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#what-to-do-when-habtm-becomes-complicated

I have used this method for a "reads" table (with post_id and user_id) as well as for subscriptions and similar kind of relationships.

Comment: You can do all this with a normal HABTM relation. Where the two differ is when you have more that id, fk1, fk2 in the join. IMO stay away from HABTM as it can be a pain to work with.

Comment: I found dealing with HABTM more complicate when i had to deal with them. As documentation says, I find this solution more simple in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

The first way is called "hasAndBelongsToMany" [[details here]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm).

The second is called "hasMany through" [[details here]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model).

The second link relating to "hasMany through" has details and a lengthy explanation about when and why you would want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the specifics of cakephp, but in general defining the relation model explicitly gives you more control over it, for instance if you wanted to do some validation or add callbacks on creation of this relationship.

Comment: You can still create the model for the join with validation. The point about control is correct though.